# How to convert Base64 encoded string to any other image formats which can be displayed in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, java, base64, png, tiff

I have a Base64 encoded string of a TIFF image type which is not working in chrome browser so I want to convert it into a any other image formats(JPG,PNG or BMP) using java/javascript. I'm looking for either server side logic in java or client side logic in javascript.

Comment: The obvious solution on server side would be to decode the base64 string into raw data, convert the image and then re-code it into base64. I am sure you will find lots of examples with any web search engine. I would not do that on client side.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to process at server side.

You can explore this- [https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/com/sun/media/jai-codec/1.1.3/jai-codec-1.1.3.jar][1]

Comment: link only answers without usage example and explanation are ususally not really useful, would be helpful if you could write more about it